# CSS Borders - outlining a group of DIVs neatly

Tags: css, border

I'm having a 'blonde moment' here - I'm sure this is easy but I can't seem to figure it out.

I have a grid of DIVs (10 rows which are CLEAR:BOTH - each with 10 FLOAT:LEFT DIVs of a fixed size).

What I want to do is assign a border to a group of these and this works (with the non-bordered sides/cells having a transparent border to keep everything aligned) BUT the way individual borders work, the 'corners' leave an ugly effect.

See this for an example

[image: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/1164739/cssborder.jpg]

Am I missing an obvious trick to just make that a solid box rather than the 'dotted line' effect the corners are creating??

To clarify my CSS - the rows have this class

```
.row {
  clear: both;
}
```

and the cells have this class

```
.cell {
  float: left;
  border: 5px solid transparent;
}
```

as well as between 0 and 4 classes like this one

```
.top { // repeated for bottom, left and right ofc.
  border-top: 5px solid black;
}
```

Comment: You should either provide your markup and css in the question, and/or make a http://jsfiddle.net for it (preferably, both).

Comment: The page is generated with jQuery so I don't really have any code to show (and even if I did, showing 100 empty DIV statements isn't going to be useful is it?)

Comment: Then add the jQuery to your jsfiddle. Also, it is certainly helpful to see empty divs if that's what your page is showing. Especially along with the CSS.

Comment: I think - to be quite honest, if you didn't get enough info from my question, you've no hope whatsoever of answering it - and posting complex jQuery which builds a whole page is just muddying the waters...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Compare this](http://jsfiddle.net/kCd7s/):

```
div {
    border: 3px solid white;
    border-right: 3px solid black;
}
```

[To this](http://jsfiddle.net/kCd7s/1/):

```
div {
    border: none;
    border-right: 3px solid black;
}
```

**EDIT**

The accepted solution was to make the padding take the place of the border, which would make the borders squared off. See:

http://jsfiddle.net/kCd7s/2/

Comment: OK - I can see what you're doing there.

The problem is, CSS Borders count as part of the size of the overall DIV - if I remove the Border (as border: none does?) then I'd have to increase the height of the DIV (by 5px for each missing border) to keep everything lined-up - which is sort-of messy!?

Comment: It's (maybe) possible that you could extend a border's value, but I doubt it (I'm not a CSS zen master). Otherwise, you'll probably need to find a way to manage the border as a single border and the background color as a "border" in this case.

Comment: By using padding to 'replace' the border where not needed, you get rid of the corners (good) BUT because a cell can have more than 1 of the border classes (top right or bottom left for example) you can't easily do that.  The only solution there would be to add 4 more classes for topleft, topright, bottomleft and bottomright I guess - it would work tho...

Comment: Having tried it, it works well enough for my purposes.  I can see an issue if you wanted to use an image as the background (rather than just a colour) as padding wouldn't extend that image - but I've no idea to do that (yet!) so I think we've got an answer!!

Comment: If old IE's is not an issue, you can apply "-moz-box-sizing: border-box;-webkit-box-sizing: border-box; box-sizing: border-box;" to divs. This way borders stop adding its width to the block. If you need IE6-7 you can still do it if you switch IE to the quirks mode, but then you'd probably need to fix you code in some other places.

Comment: @AlexeyIvanov - In [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kCd7s/5/) using `border-box`, it still has the "wedge" display problem.

Comment: I mean it will fix overall container width/height problem. Not problem with a shape of the borders. See here how it works: http://jsfiddle.net/kCd7s/6/

Answer (score 0):

If you put a border on the entire square, this is how border behaves. If you want to avoid this you should give the boxes with a black border dimensions on the sides not having a border equal to the width of the border, so add `border: none` first, then add dimensions, like if normal height is 20 and border is 5, and you want a border on the right, you would set: `height: 30; width: 25; border-right: 5px solid;`

Comment: For a raft of reasons I don't want to mess with the dimensions - the other answer hinted that you can use Padding to 'replace' the border tho and that does seem to work

Answer (score 0):

Or try [this way](http://jsfiddle.net/NGLN/TtuNT/):

```
.top::before,
.bottom::before,
.left::after,
.right::after {
    content: ".";
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: black;
    display: block;
    font-size: 0;
    position: absolute;
}
.top::before {
    height: 5px;
}
.bottom::before {
    height: 5px;
    top: 35px;
}
.left::after {
    width: 5px;
}
.right::after {
    width: 5px;
    left: 35px;
}
```